# Hint possible parameter values of a method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, typing, python-dataclasses

I have a function which is a dataclass and here I would like to overwrite its method `__getitem__` to be able to access attributes of my class. Is it possible to annotate the `__getitem__` parameter such a way to be able to get a hint of possible inputs when I use brackets ('[]') for accessing of attributes of my class? See code below..

```py
from typing import Literal

@dataclass()
class A:
    a: str
    b: str

    def __getitem__(self, item: Literal['a', 'b']) -> str:
        return getattr(self, item)


inst = A('hello', 'world')
print(inst['a']) # here I need a hint when typing inside brackets that there are possible values 'a', 'b'.
```

Comment: What you did here seems to work fine. PyCharm certainly takes it in account and shows a warning on e.g. `inst[3]` or `inst['x']`.

Comment: It unfortunately does not work for me. I would need to get a hint of available attributes when I hit CTRL+space inside brackets [].

Comment: that indeed doesn't work, but you probably want to report this on the pycharm bug tracker. PyCharm clearly understands the annotation (since it generates a warning on misuse) so what's either missing (or knowingling not done) is feedback into autocompletion.

Comment: I created the bug at PyCharm bug tracker, see here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40480

Comment: Input hints and completion aren't part of Python. Are you aiming at a specific linter, type checker or IDE?